# Cost of Math.sin() .cos() vs whacky own implementation

Tags: javascript, performance, game-engine, trigonometry

So about an hour ago I had this nice and embarrasing moment when something clicks after a really long time. Pushing 30 I finally got sinus and cosinus. After an episode that can only be described as basically reimplementing the wheel.

---

Aiming for WASD controls to move on two axes, factoring in the direction the player looks, I decided to go with a simple switch:

```
switch (key) {
case 'up':
    movement.z -= 1 * modulation.z;
    movement.x += 1 * modulation.x;
    break;
case 'down':
    movement.z += 1 * modulation.z;
    movement.x -= 1 * modulation.x;
    break;
case 'left':
    movement.x -= 1 * modulation.z;
    movement.z -= 1 * modulation.x;
    break;
case 'right':
    movement.x += 1 * modulation.z;
    movement.z += 1 * modulation.x;
    break;

...
}
```

... where modulation.z and .x would be based off the direction the player is facing. Modulation values would need to range from -1 to +1. (This should have been my first clue, yes!) So I helped myself to some trusty pen and paper and in blissfull ignorance of my 9th grade education I came up with:

```
function setModulation(rotation) {
    var rotationTemp = 0;
    var modulation = {};

    rotationTemp = rotation;
    if (rotationTemp > 180) {
        rotationTemp = 360 - rotationTemp;
    }
    rotationTemp /= 180;

    modulation.z = 1 - rotationTemp * 2;

    rotationTemp = rotation + 90;
    if (rotationTemp > 180) {
        rotationTemp = 360 - rotationTemp;
    }
    rotationTemp /= 180;

    modulation.x = 1 - rotationTemp * 2;
    modulation.x *= -1;

    return modulation;
};
```

---

Having learned and/or remembered a little in the meantime, upon revisiting this code it dawned upon me: that's a job for cos and sin. Srsly.

```
function setModulationMath(rotation) {
    var modulation = {};

    modulation.z = Math.cos(rotation * Math.PI / 180);
    modulation.x = Math.sin(rotation * Math.PI / 180);

    return modulation;
};
```

---

So far so happy! Using the Math what the math is for! But then I checked performance. And my own "implementation" is considerably faster in FF, Chrome & IE. Using 1.000.000 iterations it's somewhere between a 35% to 45% gain on my local setup.

Anyone got pointers as to why? Is it just Math.cos() / .sin()? An increase that measurable is way more than one should expect, isn't it? Anyone experienced inclined to share her*his insights?

```js
function setModulationMath(rotation) {
    var modulation = {};

    modulation.z = Math.cos(rotation * Math.PI / 180);
    modulation.x = Math.sin(rotation * Math.PI / 180);

    return modulation;
};

function setModulation(rotation) {
    var rotationTemp = 0;
    var modulation = {};

    rotationTemp = rotation;
    if (rotationTemp > 180) {
        rotationTemp = 360 - rotationTemp;
    }
    rotationTemp /= 180;

    modulation.z = 1 - rotationTemp * 2;

    rotationTemp = rotation + 90;
    if (rotationTemp > 180) {
        rotationTemp = 360 - rotationTemp;
    }
    rotationTemp /= 180;

    modulation.x = 1 - rotationTemp * 2;
    modulation.x *= -1;

    return modulation;
};

var iterations = 1000000;
console.time('setModulation');
for(var i = 0; i < iterations; i++ ){
    setModulation(i, i / 2);
};
console.timeEnd('setModulation')

console.time('setModulationMath');
for(var i = 0; i < iterations; i++ ){
    setModulationMath(i, i / 2);
};
console.timeEnd('setModulationMath')
```

Comment: I don't think the two functions produce the same result at all.

Comment: If calculating sin and cos were that easy, centuries of mathematics and engineering would have looked a lot different...

Comment: While my first assumption was that I must have somehow faked my way through it: it perfectly works. Both functions give the same modulation values. This being said: I'd be happy to be told that this is a hack that only works because [x]... :)

Comment: Perhaps your inputs are multiples of 90, or the custom function's approximation is good enough for the purpose, but for example results from `setModulation(30)` and `setModulationMath(30)` are very different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your function may very well be faster. The comparison doesn't make any sense, however, because the functions produce completely different results. Let's just take a benchmark of the error:

```
var err_z = 0;
var err_x = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < 360; ++i){
    var mm = setModulationMath(i);
    var m = setModulation(i);
    err_z += Math.abs(mm.z - m.z);
    err_x += Math.abs(mm.x - m.x);
}
```

And …

```
err_z == 49.17730025861921
err_x == 113.58865012930961
```

That's pretty bad. If the two were at all similar, you'd expect values close to 0.

> While my first assumption was that I must have somehow faked my way through it: it perfectly works. Both functions give the same modulation values. This being said: I'd be happy to be told that this is a hack that only works because [x]... :)

The average error is provably 0.137 on the z axis and 0.316 on the x axis. This might be good enough for you, but there are certainly values where the difference is higher. Are you maybe only checking the orthogonal directions? In which case, what you need is a `switch`, not trigonometry.

*edit*: Oh, and here's a graph for the z part. The squiggly line is cosine, the straight lines are your approximation.

[image: graphs]

But I digress.

It is not necessarily bad to (try to) roll your own implementation of trig functions, math functions, etc. It really depends on the specifics of the application, and sometimes you will find that you don't need such precision, or your angles will only be expressed as an integer number of degrees … In those cases, it might be beneficial to use a simpler approximation, or look-up tables.

As it is, sine and cosine in Javascript (and many other standard libraries) are very well optimised AND very precise.

Comment: That's that! Just didn't see the huge amount this was off, because I mainly checked by "is it doing what I want it to do?" and the perception of movement in a virtual room is such a bad measurement.

Comment: @JonasM.Schlatter I added a graph, which shows it really works for orthogonal directions only. Do you ever check for angles other than those?

Comment: While it is bad form to post a link and I will delete this again soon, you put that much thought into your highly appreachiated answer, here's a (short term) link to the hobby project I use this in: http://free2d.de/webgl/ - movement with wasd + qe / mouse. The hack is just used for movement.

Comment: @JonasM.Schlatter Thanks for that. The error is really not so obvious in that demo, maybe a little bit when looking down and going straight vs. going 'diagonal'. Nonetheless, I don't think your performance will suffer with Math. One way you could speed it up is to only recalculate the `modulation` values whenever the rotation changes. As it is, I think you're recalculating every frame?

Comment: Right now it's recalculating every frame that a key is pressed; to only recalculate if the rotation changes - as well as implementing Ahmad Bamieh's suggestion in his answer - is something I look forward to! ...not so much for optimizing non-bottlenecks, but to get it right and learn from your advice. :)

Answer (score 1):

Math operations are more expensive because of many reasons, but mostly because they deal with general cases and edge cases, unlike simple  multiplication and addition operations.

also object lookups and function calls are very expensive, hence caching PI is always a rule of thumb. I changed the setModulationMath operation to the following. and i used performance.now() instead of timeEnd since it is more accurate. read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now

my results:

- setModulation: 50.264999999999986ms
- setModulationMath: 68.46499999999997ms

```js
var PI180 = Math.PI/180;

function setModulationMath(rotation) {
  var rotationC = rotation * PI180;
  return {
    z: Math.cos(rotationC),
    x: Math.sin(rotationC)
  };
};


function setModulation(rotation) {
  var rotationTemp = 0;
  var modulation = {};
  rotationTemp = rotation;
  if (rotationTemp > 180) {
    rotationTemp = 360 - rotationTemp;
  }
  rotationTemp /= 180;
  modulation.z = 1 - rotationTemp * 2;
  rotationTemp = rotation + 90;
  if (rotationTemp > 180) {
    rotationTemp = 360 - rotationTemp; 
  }
  rotationTemp /= 180;
  modulation.x = 1 - rotationTemp * 2;
  modulation.x *= -1;
  return modulation;
};


var iterations = 1000000;
var t0 = performance.now();
for (var i = 0; i < iterations; i++){
  setModulation(i);
}
var t1=performance.now();
console.log("setModulation: "+(t1-t0)+"ms");


var t2 = performance.now();
for (var l = 0; l < iterations; l++){
  setModulationMath(l);
}
var t3=performance.now();
console.log("setModulationMath: "+(t3-t2)+"ms");
```

Comment: My results: setModulation: 90.29499999999985ms
setModulationMath: 31.61500000000001ms. You sir just turned that around, and the real Math is now much faster than the whacky hack! ;)